# Send any file using xmpp in cocoa application. Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xmpp, xmppframework

In my chat application, I am unable to send any **image or file** while chat. What i tried is ---

**Method 1...**

```
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:@"Send Image Testing"];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[jid full]];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[xmppStream myJID] full]];
[message addChild:body];

NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"loginLogo.png"];
NSData *imageData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];

NSData *data = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
NSString *imgStr = [NSString encodeBase64WithData:data];

NSXMLElement *ImgAttachement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"attachment"];
[ImgAttachement setStringValue:imgStr];
[message addChild:ImgAttachement];

[xmppStream sendElement:message];
```

I added a "xmlElement" named "attachment" in "message" xmlElement. String value of "attachment" is ImageDataString encoded in "Base64" format. But this code is sending only the text to other end(not image).

Don't know the cause of failure, may be i should send NSImage or server link of the image in place of image data.

**Method 2...**

I also tried "XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer" classes, with following code.

```
[_fileTransfer sendData:decodedData 
                       named:@"hello"
                 toRecipient:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"MYUSERNAME@chat.facebook.com/RESOURCENAME"]
                 description:@"Baal's Soulstone, obviously."
                       error:&err])
```

But every time this is giving the same error - `Error Domain=XMPPOutgoingFileTransferErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unable to send SI offer; the recipient doesn't have the required features."`

Please help, if any idea
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question still unclear to us, what exactly happening to this code any bug yeah crash yeah something else???

Comment: @Tirth As i edited my question, I am able to send text with above method, but problem is ----- Image is not being sent. Please help if you have any idea

Answer (score -1):

I got it working this way-

1. Inside setupStrem method, set up the incoming end like this -

   ```
   xmppIncomingFileTransfer = [[XMPPIncomingFileTransfer alloc] init];
   xmppIncomingFileTransfer.disableIBB = NO;
   xmppIncomingFileTransfer.disableSOCKS5 = NO;
   [xmppIncomingFileTransfer   activate:xmppStream];

   [xmppIncomingFileTransfer addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   ```
2. Implement the incoming end delegate methods-

   ```
   - (void)xmppIncomingFileTransfer:(XMPPIncomingFileTransfer *)sender  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"%@: Incoming file transfer failed with error: %@", THIS_FILE, error);
   }

   - (void)xmppIncomingFileTransfer:(XMPPIncomingFileTransfer *)sender  didReceiveSIOffer:(XMPPIQ *)offer
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"%@: Incoming file transfer did receive SI offer. Accepting...", THIS_FILE);
       [sender acceptSIOffer:offer];
   }

   - (void)xmppIncomingFileTransfer:(XMPPIncomingFileTransfer *)sender  didSucceedWithData:(NSData *)data
                      named:(NSString *)name
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"%@: Incoming file transfer did succeed.", THIS_FILE);

       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
       [data writeToFile:fullPath options:0 error:nil];

       DDLogVerbose(@"%@: Data was written to the path: %@", THIS_FILE, fullPath);
   }
   ```

Incoming files will be written to the documents directory, you can update UI when it is done.

3. On the sending side-

   ```
   if (!_fileTransfer) {
           _fileTransfer = [[XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

           AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

           [_fileTransfer activate:appDelegate.xmppStream];
           _fileTransfer.disableIBB = NO;
           _fileTransfer.disableSOCKS5 = NO;

           [_fileTransfer addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
       }

       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

       NSError *err;
       if (![_fileTransfer sendData:data  named:filename  toRecipient:[XMPPJID jidWithString:self.contact.primaryResource.jidStr] description:@"Baal's Soulstone, obviously."  error:&err]) {
           DDLogInfo(@"You messed something up: %@", err);
       }
   ```
4. Implement the outgoing delegate methods -

   ```
   - (void)xmppOutgoingFileTransfer:(XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer *)sender  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       DDLogInfo(@"Outgoing file transfer failed with error: %@", error);
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"There was an error sending your file. See the logs."  delegate:nil   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
   }

   - (void)xmppOutgoingFileTransferDidSucceed:(XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer *) sender
   {
       DDLogVerbose(@"File transfer successful.");
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"  message:@"Your file was sent successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];
   }
   ```

Note that the `disableIBB` and `disableSOCKS5` should match at both ends.
If the problem still exists, go to `XMPPOutgoingFileTransfer.m` and then to the method-

```
 - (void)handleRecipientDiscoInfoQueryIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq withInfo:(XMPPBasicTrackingInfo *)info
```

Then put a NSLOG/Breakpoint at this line - 

`hasSOCKS5 = hasSI && hasFT && hasSOCKS5;
hasIBB = hasSI && hasFT && hasIBB;`

Both values should become TRUE when sending a file. Check which one is FALSE (causing the error), you will get an idea why the incoming end is sending FALSE instantly. Try to fix that.

Comment: i read your answer but setupStrem method doesn't found in  xmpp demo